# TEXTTOARRAY(). Has anyone written an optimal VBA function that can do the inverse of =ARRAYTOTEXT(,1)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

At first glance, a mixture of mid and len (to remove the curly brackets) and text split would achieve this. However, this does not deal with edge cases where a semicolon or comma is present in an individual element. See the example below.

```
Let A1=1
Let B1="Semicolon ; in me"
Let A2="Comma, in me"
let B2=4

ARRAYTOTEXT(A1:B2,1)={1,"Semicolon ; in me";"Comma , in me",4} = (C)
ARAYTOTEXT_INV(C) = Spilled range identical to A1:B2
```

Now using a text split of (C) would find the semicolons and commas within the speech marks and split the text too much. I think I need some use of regex to get the desired result.

The inverse function will be applied to many such ranges so needs to be optimal. The answer needs to also be able to deal with numbers and blank values adequately.

Edit: needs to be able to solve for the below cases as well as normal text:

1. Numbers that don't have speech marks.
2. Blanks that are not surrounded by quotation marks.
3. Sets of sets (which is less likely to happen granted) such as
   {"{"a,"," b,";" a,"," b,"}","{"c,"," d,";"c,"," d,"}"}
4. Edge cases {",",";"), you can imagine an element being the formula
   "=FIND(",",a1)" for example.

In the image below you can use ARRAYTOTEXT(B3:C4,1) to get to the value in B7. I want a function that can be placed in B10 (to spill into B10:C11) to give me the original values back i.e. the inverse of ARRAYTOTEXT.
[See Excel Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC1uN.png)

Comment: No, your textsplit just needs to only look for semicolons and commas that are surrounded by quote marks. For example, if the text to split is in cell A1, use `=TEXTSPLIT(MID(A1, 3, LEN(A1)-4), """,""", """;""")`

Comment: There are four instances which this unfortunately doesn't solve for in order of most importance: 
1. Numbers which don't have speech marks.
2. Blanks which are not surrounded by quote marks. 
3. Sets of sets (which is less likely to happen granted) such as {"{""a,"",""b,"";""a,"",""b,""}","{""c,"",""d,"";""c,"",""d,""}"}
4. Edge cases {",",";"), you can imagine an element being the formula "=FIND(",",a1)" for example.

Comment: Isn't `=TOCOL(A1:B2)` what you're looking for? Else: what is your expected end result for your example?

Comment: Nope I am trying to go from the string {"a","b";"c","d"} -> to a spilled array of the four elements.

Comment: Again, what's the expected result? From given range? If you want to split it by comma and semicolon, then you would spill it back to it's original state and you could just refer to the range itself (`=A1:B2`) without further calculations. So share the expected end result please

Comment: Does the image at the bottom help? I can't just reference the range itself, as the strings are what I get from a database - to add colour to my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a crack at my own problem. This seems to work for all cases. Can anyone make this more efficient?

```vb
Function TEXTTOARRAY(inarr As String)
    Dim nDbleQuote As Long
    Dim charLng As String
    Dim BrkElum() As Long
    Dim lenArr As Long
    Dim nCol As Long, nRow As Long, nElum As Long
    Dim iLng As Long, iRows As Long, iCols As Long, iElum As Long
    Dim RowSep As String, ColSep As String
    RowSep = Application.International(xlRowSeparator)
    ColSep = Application.International(xlColumnSeparator)
    
    'Remove curly brackets
    Dim Arr As String: Arr = Mid$(inarr, 2, Len(inarr) - 2)
    
    ReDim BrkElum(1 To 1): BrkElum(1) = 0
    
    nElum = 1
    nRow = 1
    nCol = 1
    
    lenArr = Len(Arr)
    
    'Iterate through string and find break points
    For iLng = 1 To lenArr
         charLng = Mid$(Arr, iLng, 1)
        If charLng = Chr(34) Then nDbleQuote = nDbleQuote + 1
        If WorksheetFunction.IsEven(nDbleQuote) Then
            If charLng = ColSep Then
                If nRow = 1 Then nCol = nCol + 1
                nElum = nElum + 1
                ReDim Preserve BrkElum(1 To nElum)
                BrkElum(nElum) = iLng
            ElseIf charLng = RowSep Then
                nRow = nRow + 1
                nElum = nElum + 1
                ReDim Preserve BrkElum(1 To nElum)
                BrkElum(nElum) = iLng
            End If
        End If
    Next iLng
    
    ReDim Preserve BrkElum(1 To nElum + 1)
    BrkElum(nElum + 1) = lenArr + 1
    
    'Create array
    Dim ArrOut() As Variant
    ReDim ArrOut(1 To nRow, 1 To nCol)
    For iRows = 1 To nRow
        For iCols = 1 To nCol
            iElum = (iRows - 1) * nCol + iCols
            ArrOut(iRows, iCols) = Mid$(Arr, BrkElum(iElum) + 1, BrkElum(iElum + 1) - BrkElum(iElum) - 1)
            If Left$(ArrOut(iRows, iCols), 1) = Chr(34) Then 'Remove outside quotes and replace internal double double quotes with single double quotes
                ArrOut(iRows, iCols) = Replace(Mid$(ArrOut(iRows, iCols), 2, Len(ArrOut(iRows, iCols)) - 2), Chr(34) & Chr(34), Chr(34))
            ElseIf IsNumeric(ArrOut(iRows, iCols)) Then 'Check if numeric and if so change from text to number
                ArrOut(iRows, iCols) = CDbl(ArrOut(iRows, iCols))
            End If
        Next iCols
    Next iRows
    
    TEXTTOARRAY = ArrOut
    
End Function
```

You can see in the image linked below the original range in `B4:D6`.
You can see in `B8` `ARRAYTOTEXT(B4:D6,1)`.
You can see in `B10:B12` `TEXTTOARRAY(B8)` (The desired function).
You can see in `B14:D16` that all cells in `B4:D6=B10:D12`.

[How it has worked out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPJz7.png)

Comment: This slightly scrapes along the [no ChatGPT policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy). Please read this policy before posting ChatGPT content in the future.

Comment: Oh shoot, I haven't seen that before, thanks for updating me. The answer it gave was fairly flawed tbh, but just gave some inspiration. You can see by the dodgy indenting that its basically all original human work.

Comment: You should create a new question for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not so simple at all. But maybe try:

[image]

Formula in `A3`:

```
=DROP(DROP(REDUCE(0,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),LAMBDA(a,b,TOCOL(LET(x,TAKE(a,1),IF(b="""",VSTACK(NOT(x),DROP(a,1)),IF(x+ISNUMBER(--b),VSTACK(DROP(a,-1),TAKE(a,-1)&b),VSTACK(a,"")))),3))),1),-1)
```

I don't think this will tick your edge-cases.

Comment: Nice try, I like the ambition to carry this out with excel formulas, must have been fun to work this out! However I think I need a more efficient approach for my use case. Have a stab at improving my VBA approach if you think you can!

Comment: @CamalotCoder, how wouod you handle nesting? Can you include some sample data with expected results? How many levels of nesting? Etc.

Comment: What do you mean by levels of nesting? You can see on the image at the bottom of my vba answer how the function reaches the desired outcome for all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the observation that typing a formula `={1,"Semicolon ; in me";"Comma , in me",4}` produces the desired result

[image]

this can be done as a UDF using `Evaluate`,  and sensitive to the data type of the input

```vb
Function TextToArray(r As Variant) As Variant
    If TypeOf r Is Range Then
        TextToArray = Application.Evaluate(r.Value2)
    Else
        TextToArray = Application.Evaluate(r)
    End If
End Function
```

Regarding incomplete input (eg `{"a",}`) to use this you'd have to preprocess the input to add missing elements (eg an empty string `""`).  But if you do that you might as well just just process the whole string.

<sub>Note that this answer is based on your input string being a valid formula.  `{"a",}` is not a valid formula.</sub>

[image]

Comment: I like it this - it is close and simpler than mine. 
Two things for the win though 
1. On inspection it does not deal well with blanks very well. try {"a",} 
2. May we make it work on the string itself and not the range value - this would generalise it to being able to have a range or string input.

Comment: 2) That solution makes it work for strings, but now it doesn't work for when a range is entered instead. 1) Goes to #Value for some obscure reason

Comment: A further challenge might be to take into account other regional settings with different row|column separators  (e.g. `Application.International(xlRowSeparator)`, `Application.International(xlColumnSeparator)`,`Application.Internation(xlAlternatearrayseparator)`)

Comment: Its so weird that ARRAYTOTEXT(A1:A2,1) where A1 and A2 are blank gives {;} - which you're correct doesn't work if you were to just enter that as a formulas. Unfortunately it needs to still work on this to be a true inverse - shame because your solution is a far more elegant solution than mine.